# How to register a COM Component with install4j?

Tags: com, install4j

I have a COM dll I want to register while installing the application. I am using Install4j. Is there any way Install4j to register the COM component? It maybe possible to use a batch file that includes statement such as "RegSvr32 abc.dll". But It would be nice if install4j has built in support for registering COM components as most of the install makers support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 5.1, there is no support for registering COM components. You would indeed have to put the regsvr32 invocation into a batch file and call it with a "Run executable or batch file" action.